# Flutter android build stucks with folllowing error and taking too long

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, macos-big-sur

Running on MacOS - 11.5.2

Gradle version - 6.1.1

Flutter - 2.8

Just installed and setup Android studio on mac, moving from Window machine. It is taking about an hour to run debug build with the error.

..............................................................................................................................................

Here is my build log output -

```
    [ +148 ms] executing: sysctl hw.optional.arm64
    [  +31 ms] Exit code 0 from: sysctl hw.optional.arm64
    [   +3 ms] hw.optional.arm64: 1
    [  +10 ms] executing: [/Users/avinashkumar/Documents/sdk/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
    [  +13 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
    [        ] 77d935af4db863f6abd0b9c31c7e6df2a13de57b
    [   +1 ms] executing: [/Users/avinashkumar/Documents/sdk/flutter/] git tag --points-at 77d935af4db863f6abd0b9c31c7e6df2a13de57b
    [  +38 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at 77d935af4db863f6abd0b9c31c7e6df2a13de57b
    [        ] 2.8.1
    [  +12 ms] executing: [/Users/avinashkumar/Documents/sdk/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
    [  +11 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
    [        ] origin/stable
    [        ] executing: [/Users/avinashkumar/Documents/sdk/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
    [  +10 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
    [        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    [ +148 ms] executing: [/Users/avinashkumar/Documents/sdk/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
    [  +18 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
    [        ] stable
    [   +9 ms] executing: sw_vers -productName
    [  +22 ms] Exit code 0 from: sw_vers -productName
    [        ] macOS
    [        ] executing: sw_vers -productVersion
    [  +26 ms] Exit code 0 from: sw_vers -productVersion
    [        ] 11.5.2
    [        ] executing: sw_vers -buildVersion
    [  +24 ms] Exit code 0 from: sw_vers -buildVersion
    [        ] 20G95
    [  +66 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
    [   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
    [  +62 ms] executing: /Users/avinashkumar/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
    [  +24 ms] executing: sysctl hw.optional.arm64
    [  +14 ms] Exit code 0 from: sysctl hw.optional.arm64
    [        ] hw.optional.arm64: 1
    [        ] executing: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun xcodebuild -version
    [  +16 ms] Exit code 72 from: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun xcodebuild -version
    [        ] xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer tool or in PATH
    [        ] Xcode not found. Run 'flutter doctor' for more information.
    [   +2 ms] executing: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun xcodebuild -version
    [  +17 ms] Exit code 72 from: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun xcodebuild -version
    [        ] xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer tool or in PATH
    [   +5 ms] executing: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun xcodebuild -version
    [  +16 ms] Exit code 72 from: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun xcodebuild -version
    [   +1 ms] xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer tool or in PATH
    [  +61 ms] List of devices attached
               192.168.193.82:4568    device product:m21nnxx model:SM_M215F device:m21 transport_id:4
    [  +17 ms] /Users/avinashkumar/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.193.82:4568 shell getprop
    [ +154 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
    [   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
    [        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
    [  +27 ms] executing: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun xcodebuild -version
    [  +15 ms] Exit code 72 from: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun xcodebuild -version
    [        ] xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer tool or in PATH
    [  +91 ms] Skipping pub get: version match.
    [  +17 ms] Found plugin geocoder at /Users/avinashkumar/Documents/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/git/flutter_geocoder-443b875d8ec80ce525cc6e8f17dfbbbbe7fa3028/
    [  +13 ms] Found plugin cashfree_pg at /Users/avinashkumar/Documents/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cashfree_pg-2.0.5+25/
/Users/avinashkumar/Documents/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_windows-2.0.2/
    [        ] Found plugin webview_flutter at /Users/avinashkumar/Documents/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-2.0.13/
    [  +22 ms] Generating /Users/avinashkumar/StudioProjects/frihbiApp/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
    [  +31 ms] executing: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun xcodebuild -version
    [  +18 ms] Exit code 72 from: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun xcodebuild -version
    [        ] xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer tool or in PATH
    [  +64 ms] ro.hardware = exynos9611
    [        ] ro.build.characteristics = phone
    [  +85 ms] Initializing file store
    [  +17 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
    [   +5 ms] gen_dart_plugin_registrant: Starting due to {InvalidatedReasonKind.inputChanged: The following inputs have updated contents: /Users/avinashkumar/StudioProjects/frihbiApp/.dart_tool/package_config_subset,/Users/avinashkumar/StudioProjects/frihbiApp/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart}
    [        ] Found plugin webview_flutter at /Users/avinashkumar/Documents/sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter-2.0.13/
    [  +12 ms] gen_dart_plugin_registrant: Complete
    [   +2 ms] Skipping target: _composite
    [   +2 ms] complete
    [   +6 ms] Launching lib/main.dart on SM M215F in debug mode...
    [   +7 ms] /Users/avinashkumar/Documents/sdk/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart --disable-dart-dev /Users/avinashkumar/Documents/sdk/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/darwin-x64/frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root /Users/avinashkumar/Documents/sdk/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/common/flutter_patched_sdk/ --incremental --target=flutter --debugger-module-names --experimental-emit-debug-metadata -Dflutter.inspector.structuredErrors=true -DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true --output-dill /var/folders/70/cmmf6gcs6rnc4f5yhw65b05h0000gn/T/flutter_tools.91gzq8/flutter_tool.bzxZdr/app.dill --packages /Users/avinashkumar/StudioProjects/frihbiApp/.dart_tool/package_config.json -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root --initialize-from-dill build/4f2a58af27abc49ecf55570043bbf938.cache.dill.track.dill --enable-experiment=alternative-invalidation-strategy
    [  +20 ms] executing: /Users/avinashkumar/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.193.82:4568 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
    [  +30 ms] <- compile file:///Users/avinashkumar/StudioProjects/frihbiApp/.dart_tool/flutter_build/generated_main.dart
    [+1718 ms] --------- beginning of main
               01-09 09:42:11.368 I/bauth_FPBAuthService( 4894): FPBAuthService, 11607
    [  +80 ms] executing: /Users/avinashkumar/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb version
    [  +20 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
               Version 31.0.3-7562133
               Installed as /Users/avinashkumar/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
    [   +3 ms] executing: /Users/avinashkumar/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
    [  +17 ms] Building APK
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
    [  +57 ms] Using gradle from /Users/avinashkumar/StudioProjects/frihbiApp/android/gradlew.
    [ +116 ms] executing: /usr/bin/plutil -convert json -o - /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/Info.plist
    [  +31 ms] Exit code 0 from: /usr/bin/plutil -convert json -o - /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/Info.plist
    [        ] {"CFBundleName":"Android Studio","JVMOptions":{"ClassPath":"$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents\/lib\/bootstrap.jar:$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents\/lib\/extensions.jar:$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents\/lib\/util.jar:$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents\/lib\/jdom.jar:$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents\/lib\/log4j.jar:$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents\/lib\/jna.jar","JVMVersion":"1.8*,1.8+","MainClass":"com.intellij.idea.Main","Properties":{"idea.paths.selector":"AndroidStudio2020.3","idea.executable":"studio","idea.platform.prefix":"AndroidStudio","idea.vendor.name":"Google","idea.home.path":"$APP_PACKAGE\/Contents"}},"NSDesktopFolderUsageDescription":"An application in Android Studio requests access to the user's Desktop folder.","LSArchitecturePriority":["x86_64"],"CFBundleVersion":"AI-203.7717.56.2031.7935034","CFBundleDevelopmentRegion":"English","NSCameraUsageDescription":"An application in Android Studio requests access to the device's camera.","CFBundleDocumentTypes":[{"CFBundleTypeName":"Android Studio Project File","CFBundleTypeExtensions":["ipr"],"CFBundleTypeRole":"Editor","CFBundleTypeIconFile":"studio.icns"},{"CFBundleTypeName":"All documents","CFBundleTypeExtensions":["*"],"CFBundleTypeOSTypes":["****"],"CFBundleTypeRole":"Editor","LSTypeIsPackage":false}],"NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching":true,"CFBundlePackageType":"APPL","CFBundleIconFile":"studio.icns","NSHighResolutionCapable":true,"CFBundleShortVersionString":"2020.3","NSMicrophoneUsageDescription":"An application in Android Studio requests access to the device's microphone.","CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion":"6.0","CFBundleExecutable":"studio","NSLocationUsageDescription":"An application in Android Studio requests access to the user's location information.","LSRequiresNativeExecution":"YES","CFBundleURLTypes":[{"CFBundleTypeRole":"Editor","CFBundleURLName":"Stacktrace","CFBundleURLSchemes":["idea"]}],"CFBundleIdentifier":"com.google.android.studio","LSApplicationCategoryType":"public.app-category.developer-tools","CFBundleSignature":"????","LSMinimumSystemVersion":"10.8","NSDocumentsFolderUsageDescription":"An application in Android Studio requests access to the user's Documents folder.","NSDownloadsFolderUsageDescription":"An application in Android Studio requests access to the user's Downloads folder.","NSNetworkVolumesUsageDescription":"An application in Android Studio requests access to files on a network volume.","CFBundleGetInfoString":"Android Studio 2020.3, build AI-203.7717.56.2031.7935034. Copyright JetBrains s.r.o., (c) 2000-2021","NSRemovableVolumesUsageDescription":"An application in Android Studio requests access to files on a removable volume."}
    [   +8 ms] executing: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
    [  +71 ms] Exit code 0 from: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
    [        ] openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19
               OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
               OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189, mixed mode)
    [   +3 ms] executing: [/Users/avinashkumar/StudioProjects/frihbiApp/android/] /Users/avinashkumar/StudioProjects/frihbiApp/android/gradlew -Pverbose=true -Ptarget-platform=android-arm64 -Ptarget=/Users/avinashkumar/StudioProjects/frihbiApp/lib/main.dart -Pbase-application-name=android.app.Application -Pdart-defines=Zmx1dHRlci5pbnNwZWN0b3Iuc3RydWN0dXJlZEVycm9ycz10cnVl,RkxVVFRFUl9XRUJfQVVUT19ERVRFQ1Q9dHJ1ZQ== -Pdart-obfuscation=false -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Ptree-shake-icons=false -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
    [ +183 ms] Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
    [+325718 ms] ...........................................................................
    [   +5 ms] Unzipping /Users/avinashkumar/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.1.1-all/cfmwm155h49vnt3hynmlrsdst/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip to /Users/avinashkumar/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.1.1-all/cfmwm155h49vnt3hynmlrsdst
    [+1865 ms] Set executable permissions for: /Users/avinashkumar/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.1.1-all/cfmwm155h49vnt3hynmlrsdst/gradle-6.1.1/bin/gradle
    [ +244 ms] Welcome to Gradle 6.1.1!
    [        ] Here are the highlights of this release:
    [        ]  - Reusable dependency cache
    [        ]  - Configurable compilation order between Groovy/Kotlin/Java/Scala
    [        ]  - New sample projects in Gradle's documentation
    [        ] For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/release-notes.html
    [+5097 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
    [+442210 ms] > Configure project :app
    [  +12 ms] WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is deprecated.
    [        ] It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
    [        ] You will no longer be able to disable R8
    [+139872 ms] WARNING: DSL element 'useProguard' is obsolete.
    [        ] It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
    [        ] Use 'android.enableR8' in gradle.properties to switch between R8 and Proguard.
    [+910757 ms] E/flutter (24140): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(171)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot fire new event. Controller is already firing an event
    [   +2 ms] E/flutter (24140): #0      _BroadcastStreamController.add (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:249)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #1      Logger._publish (package:logging/src/logger.dart:241)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #2      Logger.log (package:logging/src/logger.dart:187)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #3      Logger.info (package:logging/src/logger.dart:216)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #4      AutoFlutterActivityController.startActivity (package:ads.acx2.tracking.activity.flutter/auto_flutter_activity_controller.dart:233)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #5      new AutoFlutterActivityController.<anonymous closure> (package:ads.acx2.tracking.activity.flutter/auto_flutter_activity_controller.dart:122)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #6      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1182)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #7      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #8      CoreActivityZoneImpl.runOutside (package:ads.acx2.tracking.activity.core.zone/zone.dart:105)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #9      AutoFlutterActivityController.runOutsideActivityZone (package:ads.acx2.tracking.activity.flutter/auto_flutter_activity_controller.dart:508)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #10     new AutoFlutterActivityController (package:ads.acx2.tracking.activity.flutter/auto_flutter_activity_controller.dart:119)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #11     new _FlutterActivityControllerImpl._internal (package:ads.acx2.tracking.activity.flutter/flutter_activity_controller.dart:170)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #12     new _FlutterActivityControllerImpl.create (package:ads.acx2.tracking.activity.flutter/flutter_activity_controller.dart:147)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #13     new FlutterActivityController (package:ads.acx2.tracking.activity.flutter/flutter_activity_controller.dart:40)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #14     AdMobAppModule.provideFlutterActivityController (package:ads.admob.fe.mobile.app/src/admob_app_module.dart:59)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #15     ProdAppInjector$Injector._createFlutterActivityController (package:ads.admob.fe.mobile.app/prod_main.inject.dart:215)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #16     ProdAppInjector$Injector._createInstrumentation (package:ads.admob.fe.mobile.app/prod_main.inject.dart:206)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #17     ProdAppInjector$Injector.instrumentation (package:ads.admob.fe.mobile.app/prod_main.inject.dart:262)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #18     _initLogger.<anonymous closure> (package:ads.admob.fe.mobile.app/src/programmatic_main.dart:148)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #19     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #20     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #21     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #22     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #23     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:285)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #24     _SyncBroadcastStreamController._sendData (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:385)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #25     _BroadcastStreamController.add (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:250)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #26     Logger._publish (package:logging/src/logger.dart:241)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #27     Logger.log (package:logging/src/logger.dart:187)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #28     Logger.info (package:logging/src/logger.dart:216)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #29     AutoFlutterActivityController.startActivity (package:ads.acx2.tracking.activity.flutter/auto_flutter_activity_controller.dart:233)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #30     new AutoFlutterActivityController.<anonymous closure> (package:ads.acx2.tracking.activity.flutter/auto_flutter_activity_controller.dart:122)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #31     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1182)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #32     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #33     CoreActivityZoneImpl.runOutside (package:ads.acx2.tracking.activity.core.zone/zone.dart:105)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #34     AutoFlutterActivityController.runOutsideActivityZone (package:ads.acx2.tracking.activity.flutter/auto_flutter_activity_controller.dart:508)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #35     new AutoFlutterActivityController (package:ads.acx2.tracking.activity.flutter/auto_flutter_activity_controller.dart:119)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #36     new _FlutterActivityControllerImpl._internal (package:ads.acx2.tracking.activity.flutter/flutter_activity_controller.dart:170)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #37     new _FlutterActivityControllerImpl.create (package:ads.acx2.tracking.activity.flutter/flutter_activity_controller.dart:147)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #38     new FlutterActivityController (package:ads.acx2.tracking.activity.flutter/flutter_activity_controller.dart:40)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #39     AdMobAppModule.provideFlutterActivityController (package:ads.admob.fe.mobile.app/src/admob_app_module.dart:59)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #40     ProdAppInjector$Injector._createFlutterActivityController (package:ads.admob.fe.mobile.app/prod_main.inject.dart:215)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #41     ProdAppInjector$Injector._createInstrumentation (package:ads.admob.fe.mobile.app/prod_main.inject.dart:206)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #42     ProdAppInjector$Injector.instrumentation (package:ads.admob.fe.mobile.app/prod_main.inject.dart:262)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #43     programmaticMain.<anonymous closure> (package:ads.admob.fe.mobile.app/src/programmatic_main.dart:79)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #44     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #45     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #46     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1630)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #47     runZonedGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1618)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #48     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1547)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #49     programmaticMain (package:ads.admob.fe.mobile.app/src/programmatic_main.dart:78)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): <asynchronous suspension>
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): #50     main (package:ads.admob.fe.mobile.app/prod_main.dart:14)
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): <asynchronous suspension>
    [        ] E/flutter (24140): 
    [+738372 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    [  +28 ms] * What went wrong:
    [        ] A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_native_image'.
    [        ] > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':flutter_native_image:classpath'.
    [        ]    > Could not download gradle-3.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1)
    [        ]       > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.1/gradle-3.3.1.jar'.
    [        ]          > Read timed out
    [        ] * Try:
    [        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    [        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    [        ] BUILD FAILED in 1h 0m 15s
    [        ] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
    [        ] Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
    [        ] See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
    [ +439 ms] [!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
    [ +875 ms] Using gradle from /Users/avinashkumar/StudioProjects/frihbiApp/android/gradlew.
    [  +76 ms] executing: [/Users/avinashkumar/StudioProjects/frihbiApp/android/] /Users/avinashkumar/StudioProjects/frihbiApp/android/gradlew -Pverbose=true -Ptarget-platform=android-arm64 -Ptarget=/Users/avinashkumar/StudioProjects/frihbiApp/lib/main.dart -Pbase-application-name=android.app.Application -Pdart-defines=Zmx1dHRlci5pbnNwZWN0b3Iuc3RydWN0dXJlZEVycm9ycz10cnVl,RkxVVFRFUl9XRUJfQVVUT19ERVRFQ1Q9dHJ1ZQ== -Pdart-obfuscation=false -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Ptree-shake-icons=false -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
    [ +180 ms] Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
    [+376064 ms] .........................................................
    [   +1 ms] Unzipping /Users/avinashkumar/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.1.1-all/cfmwm155h49vnt3hynmlrsdst/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip to /Users/avinashkumar/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.1.1-all/cfmwm155h49vnt3hynmlrsdst
    [+1744 ms] Set executable permissions for: /Users/avinashkumar/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.1.1-all/cfmwm155h49vnt3hynmlrsdst/gradle-6.1.1/bin/gradle
    [ +218 ms] Welcome to Gradle 6.1.1!
    [        ] Here are the highlights of this release:
    [        ]  - Reusable dependency cache
    [        ]  - Configurable compilation order between Groovy/Kotlin/Java/Scala
    [        ]  - New sample projects in Gradle's documentation
    [        ] For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/release-notes.html
    [+5094 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 stopped Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
```

Comment: Try updating the Android Gradle Plugin version to 7.0.4.

Comment: Look at that line: "...Could not download gradle-3.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1).."

Comment: @SujalKumar that Gradle version doesn't exist

Comment: In gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties, change this line too:  
 ​distributionUrl​=​https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip

Comment: Either use 7.0.2-bin or 7.3.3-bin in that url removing the older version already present there.

Comment: Use the flutter standard :

In your gradle-wrapper.properties :
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip

In your android/build.gradle : 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'  
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"